# IE7 document mode filename is not getting set from javascript

Tags: forms, internet-explorer-7, file-io

I am having two forms in page.One is dynamically generated and other is static one.
Both forms having input type file element.

Now I want to set dynamic form input type file element value to static form input file element.

I get the file element value in javascript but when i am trying to set that value to static form file element that time it is not getting set.

I am using browser IE which having Browser mode IE8 and document mode IE7 standard.

Please help me here.
Thanks

Comment: Show us what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

Its a security feature in browsers for you not to be able to change the value of a file input element in Javascript, you could try the input and see what you could do with the clone, however I have not tried this.